# How to prove the time complexity of Merge Sort and Insertion Sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Sorting Algorithms have different time complexities e.g. Merge sort has O(nlogn), insertion and selection have O(n^2). How to prove that Merge Sort has the Time Complexity of O(nlogn), Insertion and Selection sorts have O(n^2) time complexity in the average case.

Comment: Do trial runs and time them. Or count the number of operations. Or just watch The Sound of Sorting on YouTube. By the time someone gets to Big-O, you should have the ability to run these tests.

Comment: BTW: a question should be one, specific question. So this should be just about one sort algorithm. Secondly, it is frowned upon when there is no trace of any research effort nor any effort of attempt.

Answer (score 0):

**The Time complexity of the merge sort for the arrays is O(n(log(n))**.

**PsuedoCode**: The arrays divides always into two equal halves if keep on dividing until the one element remains to be a divide. For every call of the division of the array, the factor depends upon the (previouslengtharray)/2. While merging the two halve the worst case found in the first case call of merging and the time complexity for merging equal to the length of the array i.e n and the division of the list takes place unit log(n). Hence the time complexity is O(n(log(n)).

```
 MergeSort(arr[], left,  right)
If rigth > left
     1. Find the middle point to divide the array into two halves:  
            middle = left+ (right-left)/2
     2. Call mergeSort for first half:   
             Call mergeSort(arr, left, middle)
     3. Call mergeSort for the second half:
             Call mergeSort(arr, middle+1, right)
     4. Merge the two halves sorted in step 2 and 3:
             Call merge(arr, left, middle, right)


Proof:

    |         n
    |       /   \
    |      /     \
    |    n/2  +   n/2 =n
    |    / \     /  \
    |   /   \   /    \
 logn  (n/4+n/4  n/4+n/4) =n Timecomplexity (n(logn))
```

**For Selection sort and insertion sort the average time-complexity will be O(n^2)**. When the maximum element found in the nearly last position of the array. We can modify the selection similar to the bubble sort algorithm if the smaller element not found on the current index we simply break the outer loop. This somewhat decreases the average time complexity of the selection sort.